# Finding location of Images in HTML/CSS template

Tags: css, image, url

I am trying to modify a template and am unable to locate the images on the very bottom right of the page (social media icons): http://flockwithme.com/

I would like to replace them with different icons, but none of the files (css, js, etc.) contain the location of the files.

If anyone could help me modify/replace them, I'd appreciate it very much. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First off, the icons are not images but are actually part of a web font defined as `"font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';"` in the application's css.

Which I assume is this one - http://graphicburger.com/simple-line-icons-webfont/ ?

Second, you can easily inspect an element's html/css code by:

1. Viewing the website in Chrome
2. Right clicking the element (in this case, the icon)
3. And choosing "Inspect Element"

Answer (score 0):

In this page they use fonts for that icons. You should see the fonts for that.

Answer (score 0):

thats not image. it set in **before** of every span 
like this

```
  .icon-social-twitter:before {
      content: "\e009";
   }
```

they using  **font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';**